# Read/Write/Change the contents of a local text file (on DropBox) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a simple HTML site located in a DropBox folder (so that it can be accessed publicly) with a couple of text files in the same folder. What I want to do is to be able to read or delete the text out of a text file and write new text in it. I've been searching for code like this for hours but all I get is code that only works with Internet Explorer or Mozilla Firefox, or I get the answer "It's not possible.".
So how can I do this in Chrome (please)?
I just need to be able to change those files and read them and I'd be so happy!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on whether Dropbox handled requests correctly for html? Just cuz you put an "HTML site" on Dropbox, doesn't mean it will run, correct?

Provided that you've looked into that, then I think you should provide some code or specifics issues/errors you're having. I don't think this particular medium is good for "ideas", or for people to write your whole application for you.

Comment: you just need to nail down the file list, file upload, and file fetch routines. you can just use a textarea to edit the contents in any browser. links can trigger an api fetch that dumps in the textarea, while a button uses the API upload to send the .value of the textarea to dropbox using the same name as was loaded. Typically, the permissions and authentication parts of these sort of things are way more complex than the actual task.

Comment: Yeah but I want to change the files out of my JavaScript/HTML file. DropBox allows it, but it doesn't have an API for it though. So yeah I just need the code for how I can read and write text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your request mentions editing local files you could use the FileReader API to do this. Here is a snippet that can read a locally stored file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <input type="file"  />
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
    var input = document.querySelector("input");
    input.addEventListener("change", function() {
      var file = input.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        document.querySelector("#output").innerText = e.target.result;
      };

      reader.readAsText(file);
    }, false);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After this you can either create a download for the newly modified file or explore the FileEntry API to actually write the contents back. This API although is pretty limited in adoption. But this should be a good starting point for you.